# React functional components- say its not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

i am using react functional components (infact learning hooks ), so i am facing one issue when calling a function with in another function

here is my code

## my functional component

```
    const LiteraryPage = props => {
      if (Object.keys(mainData).length === 0 && mainData.constructor === Object) {
        setMainDataSection(validateData(mainData));
      }
      const validateData = async (data) => {
    let finalDataArray = [];
    if (data.cars !== undefined) {
      finalDataArray = finalDataArray.concat(data.cars);
    }
    if (data.mobiles !== undefined) {
      finalDataArray = finalDataArray.concat(data.mobiles);
    }
    if (data.scooters !== undefined) {
      finalDataArray = finalDataArray.concat(data.scooters);
    }
    return finalDataArray;
  };

 
    }
```

But am getting a error

Uncaught TypeError: validateData is not a function

Please correct me if am missing something or if am wrong at some place.

Comment: validateData, should be defined before you use it. Just change the order.

Comment: Is it possibly complaining about the function being used before it was defined?

Comment: @JulioVásconez i changed the order, that time am getting some infinite loop error

Comment: @DrewReese ^^. please see above comment

Comment: What does `setMainDataSection(validateData(fullAssetsData))` do? If it somehow changes props value sent to component, and the condition is always true, then that could cause infinite loop.

Comment: @DrewReese
  const validateData = async (data) => {
    let finalDataArray = [];
    if (data.cars !== undefined) {
      finalDataArray = finalDataArray.concat(data.cars);
    }
    if (data.buses !== undefined) {
      finalDataArray = finalDataArray.concat(data.buses);
    }
    if (data.mobiles !== undefined) {
      finalDataArray = finalDataArray.concat(data.mobiles);
    }
    return finalDataArray;
  };

Comment: @DrewReese added the same in question

Comment: Maybe if you use an editor like vscode your code would format properly and tell you you can't use `validateData` before it's defined as Julio already mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are possibly setting a state directly inside the functional component when you are calling validate data and setMainDataSection.

So Firstly you need to define validateData before using it and secondly, you need to execute your check in a useEffect

```js
const LiteraryPage = props => {
  const validateData = async (data) => {
    let finalDataArray = [];
    if (data.cars !== undefined) {
      finalDataArray = finalDataArray.concat(data.cars);
    }
    if (data.mobiles !== undefined) {
      finalDataArray = finalDataArray.concat(data.mobiles);
    }
    if (data.scooters !== undefined) {
      finalDataArray = finalDataArray.concat(data.scooters);
    }
    return finalDataArray;
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(mainData).length === 0 && mainData.constructor === Object) {
      setMainDataSection(validateData(mainData));
    }
  }, []);

}
```

Comment: can you tell me why i need to put the same under useEffect ?

Comment: Because if you don't, that part of code is executed on every render and it will cause an infinite loop since it causes another re-render due to `setMainDataSection`